# creating AWS S3 bucket with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

Below is my yml file to create S3 bucket. For security purpose i have not pasted here actual aws_access_key and aws_secret_key just showing them as ***** in the snippet below. I have installed boto3, boto,AWS CLI on the Ec2 instance which is having Ansible installed on it.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create an S3 bucket
    become: true
    aws_s3: aws_access_key=****** aws_secret_key=**** bucket=testbuck  mode=create permission=public-read region=us-east-1
```

when i execute above yml file using ansible-playbook command then it gives exception as shown below.
Please help me to fix this issue so that a S3 bucket with name "testbuck" gets created.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.10.44", "botocore_version": "1.13.44", "changed": false, "error": {"code": "403", "message": "Forbidden"}, "msg": "Failed while looking up bucket (during bucket_check) testbuck.: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden", "response_metadata": {"host_id": "OmIY2bLkh4T4JwxD/UJsM47n7oUUS6ttEL9ZMl+vv66bVsLcwQuP2pzAGr05m1LdtznYudrrapk=", "http_headers": {"content-type": "application/xml", "date": "Fri, 17 Jan 2020 16:54:49 GMT", "server": "AmazonS3", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "x-amz-bucket-region": "us-east-1", "x-amz-id-2": "OmIY2bLkh4T4JwxD/UJsM47n7oUUS6ttEL9ZMl+vv66bVsLcwQuP2pzAGr05m1LdtznYudrrapk=", "x-amz-request-id": "51740FB276A10A18"}, "http_status_code": 403, "request_id": "51740FB276A10A18", "retry_attempts": 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the Ansible command runs with [check if a bucket exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html) before creating it. Maybe the IAM user you use doesn't have the permissions to check if the bucket exists. Try to add:

`aws_s3: ... ignore_nonexistent_bucket: True`

Or grant the `s3:ListBucket` permission to the user.

Comment: My user is admin user which has all the permissions. As suggested by you i modified my yml  to include ignore_nonexistent_bucket=true.
aws_s3: aws_access_key=****** aws_secret_key=**** bucket=testbuck  mode=create permission=public-read region=us-east-1 ignore_nonexistent_bucket=true

Comment: Now yml is not giving error and it is executed successfully but bucket "testbuck" is not created. Below is the output of yml

[root@redhat ~]# ansible-playbook create_S3_bucket.yml

TASK [Create an S3 bucket] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: That's most probably because `testbuck` exists in some another account and the bucket names should be globally unique, try to set a unique bucket name.

Comment: Thanks Yann for all the help around this. It is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should need to check whether `s3:ListBucket` access is there. This is the official s3 documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadBucket.html

Answer (score 0):

The `HeadBucket` action is to check if an s3 bucket exists and you have permissions to it. To use this operation your IAM role/user must have the ability to perform `s3:ListBucket` action. The bucket owner has this permission by default and grant this permission to other. For more information refer to the s3 official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadBucket.html